# list of users is not updating after insert into mysql database in node.js/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

`users/form` render a form to insert a new user.  `/user_create`, connects to the database and insert the user correctly but then when redirecting to `users` it´s not loading the new user. If I refresh it appears. It´s not loading from the database when redirecting?

```
router.post('/user_create', (req,res) => { 
    const name      = req.body.create_first_name;
    const email     = req.body.create_email;
    const address   = req.body.create_address;
    const phone     = req.body.create_phone;

    const queryString = "INSERT INTO client (id,name,email,address,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    getConnection().query(queryString, [null,name,email,address,phone], (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: "+err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return
        }
        console.log("Insertes new user with id: ", results.insertId);
        res.end();
    });
    res.redirect("/users");
});

//GET users
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    const connection = getConnection();

    const newLocal = "SELECT * FROM client";
    connection.query(newLocal,(err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: "+err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        res.json(rows);
    }); 
});

router.get("/users/form", (req, res) => {
    res.render("form.ejs");
});
```

In form.ejs:

```
       <form action="/user_create" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="create_first_name"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="create_email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="create_address">
            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="create_phone">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Access to database:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass',
    port: 3306, 
    database: 'databaseName'
}); 

function getConnection() {
    return pool;
}
```

Comment: looks to me you are redirected before the db operation is run.  add `console log` inside `router.get` function before `const connection` to check if this console log shows before your console log inside `getConnection`

Comment: yes, is doing that. I didn´t know it could do that. Should I put res.redirect("/users"); after console.log("Insertes new user with id: ", results.insertId); ?

Comment: yes, put your redirect before res.end()